# Connection between the quantum calculus and fractional calculus developed by Riemann-Liouvelle, Caputo and others?

Tags: reference-request, fractional-calculus, quantum-calculus

I wonder are there any connection between the quantum calculus and fractional calculus developed by Riemann-Liouvelle, Caputo and others?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there isn't even a "the" fractional calculus.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Sorry to be blunt but the bounty you just decided to offer should not be used as a compensation for your laziness in asking this question, which made that you omitted every kind of context. You might instead start by explaining how [this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_Schr.C3.B6dinger_equation_in_quantum_theory) does not address your concerns...