# What is the relation between quantum calculus and fractional calculus?

Tags: calculus

Why did we need the fractional calculus? Does It have any relation with the quantum calculus or discrete quantum calculus?

Comment: They're really quite different beyond the fact that they both might put subscripts on common Calculus symbols. Is there a reason you expect a connection? Are you more interested in, say, applications of various conceptions of fractional Calculus beyond what you can find from a Google search? It would help a lot for context if you could list what you've found out and explain why you were not satisfied with it.

Comment: They are very different. Concerning fractional calculus, these two posts [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/applications-of-fractional-calculus) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705230/fractional-calculus-motivation-and-foundations) could be of interest.

Comment: Not very helpful, but related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2382689/272831

Comment: Also, please do not repost.  Edit previous questions, place bounties, etc.